Flutter VsCode Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): ' ' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
I updated Flutter to 3.27 and Xcode to 16.2 and now I can't build iOS from VsCode anymore.
I get a flurry of error all saying this or that is available in iOS 13 or newer but my build target is iOS 13 every.
Even more confusing I can build perfectly fine from Xcode. The one interesting thing about my project is that is has an Apple Watch app in the project as well. It looks like it's attempting to build watch code when it builds the iOS app. but it never did that before I updated.
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.27.0, on macOS 15.2 24C101 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.96.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!


Launching lib/main_prod_debug.dart on Connor’s iPhone in debug mode...
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading project.pbxproj
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: U8W7UB7GVT
Xcode build done.                                           23.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Published' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Runner/WatchConnectivity.swift:26:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Published' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/WatchCommunicationManager.swift:12:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'ObservableObject' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/WatchCommunicationManager.swift:11:49

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'WatchCommunicationManager' does not conform to protocol 'WCSessionDelegate'
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/WatchCommunicationManager.swift:30:0

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:13:30

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:13:40

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'black' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:13:46

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:13:53

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'black' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:13:59

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:14:32

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:14:42

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'init(_:bundle:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:14:42

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:14:69

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'init(_:bundle:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:14:69

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'some' return types are only available in iOS 13.0.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:16:14

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'View' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:16:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'some' return types are only available in iOS 13.0.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:41:25

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'View' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationView.swift:41:30

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'some' return types are only available in iOS 13.0.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ConnectionIssueView.swift:10:14

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'View' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ConnectionIssueView.swift:10:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Preview(_:body:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ConnectionIssueView.swift:58:1

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'isLuminanceReduced' is only available in iOS 16.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:13:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Preview(_:body:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:505:1

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Preview(_:body:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/DataIssueView.swift:57:1

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find type 'WKUserNotificationHostingController' in scope
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationController.swift:14:30

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Property does not override any property from its superclass
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationController.swift:21:17

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationController.swift:26:18

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationController.swift:31:18

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/NotificationController.swift:36:18

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'ObservableObject' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/BatteryManager.swift:12:22

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find type 'WKApplicationDelegate' in scope
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/AppDelegate.swift:13:29

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Published' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/DeliveryQueue.swift:15:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'ObservableObject' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/DeliveryQueue.swift:10:21

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'scenePhase' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/Six_Watch_DesignApp.swift:12:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'main()' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/Six_Watch_DesignApp.swift:9:0

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Unknown attribute 'WKApplicationDelegateAdaptor'
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/Six_Watch_DesignApp.swift:11:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Environment' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/Six_Watch_DesignApp.swift:12:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'some' return types are only available in iOS 13.0.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/Six_Watch_DesignApp.swift:15:14

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Scene' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/Six_Watch_DesignApp.swift:15:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Six_Watch_Design_Watch_AppApp' does not conform to protocol 'App'
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/Six_Watch_DesignApp.swift:10:7

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKWorkoutSession' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:19:24

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKLiveWorkoutBuilder' is unavailable in iOS
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:20:24

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKLiveWorkoutBuilder' is unavailable in iOS
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:328:57

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKLiveWorkoutBuilder' is unavailable in iOS
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:332:42

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKLiveWorkoutBuilderDelegate' is unavailable in iOS
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:327:27

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKWorkoutSession' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:349:42

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKWorkoutSessionState' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:349:81

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKWorkoutSessionState' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:349:120

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'HKWorkoutSession' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/General/WatchWorkoutTracking.swift:353:42

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'scenePhase' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:12:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Environment' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:12:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Environment' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:13:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:15:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:16:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:17:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:19:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:20:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:22:30

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:22:40

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'black' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:22:46

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:22:53

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'black' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:22:59

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:23:32

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:23:42

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'init(_:bundle:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:23:42

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'Color' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:23:69

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'init(_:bundle:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:23:69

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:25:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:26:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:27:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:28:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:29:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:32:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:33:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:34:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'State' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:36:5

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'publisher(for:object:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:38:56

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'publisher(for:object:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:39:57

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'publisher(for:object:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:40:63

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'publisher(for:object:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:42:55

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'publisher(for:object:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:43:55

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'some' return types are only available in iOS 13.0.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:164:14

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'View' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/ContentView.swift:164:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'ObservableObject' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/AppleWatchManager.swift:11:25

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'some' return types are only available in iOS 13.0.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/DataIssueView.swift:10:14

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'View' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
/Users/connor/Documents/SIX/ios/Six%20Watch%20App/DataIssueView.swift:10:19

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code

Error launching application on Connor’s iPhone.

Exited (1).

